# Plotting data on quadrilateral area

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot

[image: Red is the area where I will be plotting data]

Hello, 
I am going through d3.js data plotting. The below image has the two examples for better understanding. Conside that I am trying to plot data on a specific area(red area) . In image 1 it is easy for me to specify range in d3,

```
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([a,b]).range([0, 100 ])
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([a,b]).range([100, 0 ])
```

With that range, I was able to plot data on any area inside the red for figure one.

But same range mechanism cant be used to plot on red area of second fig as x value at top is different from x value at bottom.

Is there any way to specify range of area to d3 to plot data on custom shapes like these?

Comment: In your snippet, you're confusing domain with range.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am looking on how to specify varying domain values at top and bottom

Comment: I understood that, it's a interesting question. I'm just saying that, in your code, `domain` and `range` are swapped.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question. Unfortunately, D3 has no native method to do what you want. However, this can be done creating a custom function, which returns the modified `x` position according to the `y` position.

There are several different ways for doing this. In my solution, I'm passing to the function a whole object in this format:

```
{x: someValue, y: someValue}
```

You may have to change the function according to your data structure, that's not important. What's important here is the general idea.

Well, here is the function:

```
function calculateXPos(obj) {
    var verticalScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 100])
        .range([0, 20]);

    var horizontalScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 100]);

    horizontalScale.range([0 + (verticalScale(obj.y)), 100 - (verticalScale(obj.y))]);

    return horizontalScale(obj.x);
}
```

What does it do?

#### Explanation

As you can see, the function has as parameter an object with two properties, `x` and `y`. Using a linear D3 scale...

```
var verticalScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([0, 20]);
```

... the function calculates the change in the range according to the `y` position of the point...

```
horizontalScale.range([0 + (verticalScale(obj.y)), 100 - (verticalScale(obj.y))]);
```

... and returns the `x` position with the customised range:

```
return horizontalScale(obj.x);
```

As you can see, there are a lot of hardcoded values in that function, as the range of the vertical scale and the differences (also as range) in the horizontal scale. Again, this is just for demonstrating the general idea, the values can be changed.

#### Live demo

Let's see it working. The first step is creating the data in the structure mentioned above. For that, I have these two loops:

```
var data = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
        data.push({
            x: i * 10,
            y: j * 10
        });
    }
}
```

That creates a square matrix. If we simply plot these points using a normal, regular D3 scale, this is what we get:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var data = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
        data.push({
            x: i * 10,
            y: j * 10
        });
    }
}

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([100, 0]);

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([0, 100]);

var gX = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(30,130)").call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(5));

var gY = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(30,30)").call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5));

var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(30,30)");

var points = g.selectAll("foo")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("fill", "firebrick")
    .attr("r", 2)
    .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.x))
    .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.y));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

However, if we use our function (passing the whole object `d`), this is what we get:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var data = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
        data.push({
            x: i * 10,
            y: j * 10
        });
    }
}

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([100, 0]);

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([0, 100]);

var gX = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(30,130)").call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(5));

var gY = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(30,30)").call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5));

var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(30,30)");

var points = g.selectAll("foo")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("fill", "firebrick")
    .attr("r", 2)
    .attr("cx", d => calculateXPos(d))
    .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.y));

function calculateXPos(obj) {
    var verticalScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 100])
        .range([0, 20]);

    var horizontalScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 100]);

    horizontalScale.range([0 + (verticalScale(obj.y)), 100 - (verticalScale(obj.y))]);

    return horizontalScale(obj.x);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Which is the trapezium you described in your question.